# How can I change xfce bottom panel to the top?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 12.10 and would like to change the panel which is currently on the bootm to the top.  This is the opposite of what most people using Unity want to do.

I have done this in the past but have forgotten how and could not find the info easily this time.
Cheers,

Answer (score 113, accepted):

1. Right-click on the panel.
2. Expand **Panel**.
3. Click **Panel Preferences**
4. Uncheck **Lock Panel**.
5. Click **Close**.

On the leftmost or rightmost side of the panel will be a double dotted line, which acts as a handle. Next:

1. Click the handle and drag the panel to the top.
2. Optionally, re-lock the panel.

Comment: Additionaly in this case you want probably to **remove the default bottom "little" "mac-like" panel** to do so, right click on it > Panel > Panel Preferences and at the very top there is a dropdown to select Panel  - click "minus"/remove icon - confirm and you're done - now there is probably nothing left to disturb the new nice bottom position of main Panel :) .